# Does the Google Cast SDK Developer Console support role based user management?

Tags: google-cast

As an IT engineer, I'm trying to enable my developers to access the Google Cast SDK Developer Console in a secure way but I can't figure out how to invite them and assign them role-based permissions.

I've signed up to access the console with a central admin account and reviewed the available menu options. The settings menu only offers a way to update contact information and communication preferences. Otherwise I can add an application or device.

I've talked to our developers and reviewed the documentation and don't seem to be able to find anything related to this. I'm open to any solution that would allow me to securely manage user access.